# Angular: compile google maps infoWindow content to use ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add a ng-click handler to some dynamic html in my infoWindow as below, which works fine for regular angular directives, but not here with the infoWindow:

```
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          console.log('will compile',marker.cinemaInfo);
          var html = $compile(marker.cinemaInfo)(scope); 
          infowindow.setContent(html);
        }
        infowindow.open(scope.map,marker);
        scope.$apply();
      });
```

Comment: try applying scope after `infowindow.setContent(html);` method

Comment: I am having the same problem; on the other hand, my code is like
var html = $compile(marker.cinemaInfo)(scope); 
          infowindow.setContent(html[0].outerHTML);

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, although there are some posts saying people need outerHTML, in my case, I have the following version working:

```
var html = $compile(marker.cinemaInfo)(scope); 
infowindow.setContent(html[0]);
```

INSTEAD OF:

```
var html = $compile(marker.cinemaInfo)(scope); 
infowindow.setContent(html[0].outerHTML);
```